# "Dreams are messages from the deep."

Tags: dialogue, dune-2021

In the film *Dune (2021)*, why was this line, "Dreams are messages from the deep." spoken in an alien voice/language? This entire film felt like a dream. What does it mean?

Comment: I haven't seen the new film and it's been some time since I read any of the novels, but this review attempts to answer the Q with the idea that "Paul's dreams" factor into all the pressure and mistrust he feels. https://piedmontroar.com/9574/sliderposts/dune-movie-review-the-importance-of-dreams/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CDreams%20are%20messages%20from%20the,this%20line%20is%20so%20important.

Answer (score 2):

> This entire film felt like a dream

There is a popular fans theory (never confirmed) that the whole film is indeed a dream of Leto II, the God Emperor. He was heavily using prescience, and could essentially see into the past and future freely.

"Dreams are messages from the deep." is not a sentence from the books, it was added by the film director, so it might be a hint the above theory is correct.

Comment: The film being a dream/ancestral memory of Leto II is great.  Inspired by your answer, some internet sleuthing turned up this [interview with the film's editor Joe Walker](https://blog.frame.io/2021/10/27/art-of-the-cut-dune-joe-walker/) mentioning the creation/use of the voice/message at the opening.

Comment: And someone [spliced together the opening chant with the Sardukar chanter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBO5olzZVZY) on Salusa Secondus.  They're the same.